# Commanline or Powershell script to turn off / on using Proxy Server in Windows

Tags: cmd.exe

Is there any script that can turn on/off using Proxy Server setting. I did some research but no luck to find the right answer.
I tried this one but not able to make it.

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t 
REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following PowerShell script will disable the proxy:

```
$regKey="HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
Set-ItemProperty -path $regKey ProxyEnable -value 0 -ErrorAction Stop
Set-ItemProperty -path $regKey ProxyServer -value "" -ErrorAction Stop
Set-ItemProperty -path $regKey AutoConfigURL -Value "" -ErrorAction Stop       
Write-Output "Proxy is now Disabled"
```

You may easily translate this code to `reg` commands, if required.

Comment: I ran the script and REGISTRY KEY shows all set but proxy button is still ON. Any idea where went wrong. (I rebooted PC but the proxy button is still ON)

Comment: See my screenshot of REGKEY

Comment: Any help about this !

Comment: I know what went wrong. I need to restart the PC in order to make it works. Thanks. 
Just curious if I want to enable it, can I change all the values to "1" ? How about the ErrorAction ???